# Take a screenshot and send it to a client with node js

Tags: javascript, server, client, screenshot

I would like to take a screenshot (of my desktop for instance) and immediately send it to a client without saving it anywhere. I am aware of npm package called 'desktop-screenshot', but as far as I'm concerned it saves the image. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Could you precise where is running your node process ?

Comment: You could take a look at the source code of 'desktop-screenshot' and take a look at what it's doing.

Comment: Why is saving so bad?

Comment: where do you want to send the image to ?